# vim compile and run hotkey does not pause after output

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set up a hotkey in vim that will save, compile, and run the current file.  So far I've spent at least an hour trying to get this to work, so it's probably cancelled out any time-saving benefit of having such a hotkey, but that's the story of my life ;)

If I type `:w` and press enter, followed by `:!g++ % -o %< && ./%<` and press enter, this works, and it shows "press enter or type command to continue" after the output, which lets me look at the output before returning to vim.  I should be able to map this to the F8 key by putting this line in `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <F8> :w <CR> :!g++ % -o %< && ./%<<CR>
```

And that runs all the commands when I press F8, but it immediately returns to vim at the end, instead of pausing with *"press enter or type command to continue"*, so I can't see the output.  If I remove the `<CR>` at the end, then I need to press enter after pressing F8.

Anyone know vim really well and know what I did wrong, or have tried something similar?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I would suggest you look at `:h :make`. If the `'makeprg'` setting is set correctly the `:make` command will compile/make your project and populate the `quickfix` list with errors. You can use `:cnext` and `:cprevious` to move through the list or use `:copen` to open the quickfix list in a window. As for getting the output of your program maybe something like this: `:nnoremap <f8> :exe 'new +r!'.expand('%<')<bar>0d_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping works for me (with proper prompting; terminal Vim 7.4.135 on Linux). Some remarks:

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- The space before the second `:!` command causes the cursor to move right, as it's interpreted in normal mode.
- You can combine both Ex commands into a single command-line.
- Though it doesn't do harm here, you'd better escape the `<` character as `<lt>`.
- As Peter Rincker already commented, the use of `:make` is preferred over explicit triggering of the compiler.

Ergo:

```
:nnoremap <F8> :w<Bar>!g++ % -o %<lt> && ./%<lt><CR>
```

Comment: Your version worked for me, and I also got `:make` to work.  Thanks!